# Change IRA contribution to prior year

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira, contribution

I under-contributed to my IRA for tax year 2018. I'd like to apply some of my 2019 contributions to tax year 2018 to reach the 2018 tax year IRA contribution maximum. We have not yet reached to 2019 filing deadline date.

How do I do this?

Comment: At least for filing purposes, you don't need to provide contribution dates, do you? Can you just count the early 2019 contributions as though they occurred in 2018, and remember not to count those same contributions for tax year 2019? See e.g. https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/when-can-ira-contributions-be-backdated-to-the-pri-3015077.html.

Comment: If you already made that deposit, you have to get the broker to acknowledge the year that you want it credited for.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: "wake knowledge" makes no sense in that sentence, did you mean "take notice" or something else?

Comment: Fixed. "Note to self - no texting while running on treadmill" - voice recognition awful with background noise.

Comment: @chepner+ _you_ don't file contribution dates, but the custodian (bank, broker, etc.) sends 5498 to IRS (and copy to you) indicating which year the contribution is for, and your returns must match that, so you must have given directions to the custodian by April 15. I hope you can get through to them tomorrow, since they tend to be very busy on the deadline day due to hordes of people who waited to the last minute.

Comment: Poss dupe https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/57466/how-late-can-i-put-money-into-an-ira-and-still-have-it-count-for-2015?rq=1